# MVVM команда с CanExecute без параметров - это нормально?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Может ли `CanExecute` не быть функцией от параметра или это плохая практика?

Например, возможность выполнения команды зависит от нескольких свойств VM. Как в этом случае правильнее поступить?

Вариант 1

```
bool CanExecute()
{
    return Prop1 && Prop2 == 1 && Prop3 is SomeType;
}
```

Вариант 2

Передать в разметке xaml в параметр все нужные свойства через `MultiBinding`, обернуть их в конвертер, который просто вернет `object[]` как `object` и в `CanExecute` использовать его?

В общем то я сам не вижу ничего плохого в первом варианте, единственное что меня смущает - привязанность функций команды к конкретному контексту, в котором они расположены.

Comment: `CanExecute` вполне может обходится без параметра.

Comment: @Bulson, я это понимаю. Оно может просто возвращать true. Но вопрос мой не про это, а про то, что если таки для результата нужны какие то свойства VM, то их нужно передавать как параметр или можно просто к ним обратиться внутри `CanExecute`? Точнее, я понимаю, что это технически возможно, но насколько это правильно? Ведь не все правильно, что технически возможно

Comment: @Bulson, короче, если обобщить всю эту информацию, то вопрос будет звучать так: "Должна ли команда быть независимой от VM или не обязательно?"

Comment: Команду можно считать оберткой вокруг метода. Того метода, который должен выполниться по событию из вьюшки. Этот метод находится во вьюмодел, его "исполнимость" или возможность запуска на выполнение может иметь зависимость как от наличия необходимых данных во вьюмодел, так и от данных передаваемых из вьюшки через параметр команды.

Comment: Если для определения возможности выполнения команды все исходные данные находятся в значениях свойств вьюмодел, то в `CanExecute` вам параметр не нужен совсем; вы и так сможете определить по значениям свойств во вьюмодел можно выполнять команду или нет.